# curl unescape output file name

Tags: bash, curl, escaping

if URL has `%20` in file name, specify `-O` will keep it, while space is preferred.

libcurl has `curl_easy_unescape`, but the curl binary in bash doesn't seem to have an easy way to unescape output file name. However, wget does unescape by default.

currently I extract file name from url, unescape it, then use `-o`.

I would like to know if an easier/builtin way exists.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you currently use?

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately there's currently no way to tell curl to URL decode the file name -O creates. It feels like a good idea to offer in the future...